# How can I make css inline?

Tags: css

How can I make all the css in the `twentyseventeen` theme appear inline? I already tried putting the following in header.php:

```
<style>
    <?php include("/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css");?>
</style>
```

and it did not work.

Comment: try simply 'style.css', as both are in the same folder

Comment: I created a child theme of it, but I still use `style.css` from `twenty seventeen`.

Comment: why do you want it inline? this talks about the correct way to enqueue parent and child themes https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/. alternatively try `'../twentyseventeen/style.css'`since both folders are under the same themes folder

Comment: Inline is supposed to be faster.

Comment: Inlining "critical css" is faster, but probably not the entire stylesheet in the header. I'd recommend just putting the header/nav and critical css elements in there and take them out of the child css. I do hope you're working on a child of the theme and not the theme itself? If not, your changes will get removed every time you update.

Comment: Yes, it's a child theme of twenty seventeen.

Comment: Cut everything out of style.css except the top commented-out part (this is required for WordPress to run, style.css can't be without this commented out code) and paste that css code between the style tags. Don't include the style.css file as you'll just end up duplicating all that css code. Not a lot of benefit to doing this, though, as I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, taking out the beginning `/` solved my issue:

```
<style>
    <?php include("wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css");?>
</style>
```

After doing this, I removed it because I realized how much slower it made the page load.

Comment: this might actually work, but you should never include with relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it inline:

```
    <style>
        <?php $css_file = file_get_contents( 'http://yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css' );
        echo '<style type="text/css">' . $css_file . '</style>';
    </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `wp_register_style()`

```
// Include stylesheets
function stylename() {
    wp_register_style( 'stylename', '/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylename' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'stylename' );
```

Comment: hmmm that is not **inline**